# Влияет ли на оптимизацию большое количество страниц Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Например, у меня в приложении есть большое количество кнопок, каждая из которых ведет на свою страницу с текстом и какой-либо информацией. Оптимально ли для каждой кнопки создавать отдельную xaml страницу с контентом или было бы логичнее использовать одну страницу, в которую подгружать контент динамически?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если контент одинаковый (например заголовок и текст), то зачем писать разные страницы? Используйте одну и подгружайте туда данные. Если же контент разный и надо его по разному отобразить, то естественно надо писать разные страницы.